# Is there a real function with the following properties?

Tags: functions

Does there exist the function $f(x)$, satisfying all of the following conditions:

(a) $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$.

(b) $f(1)=\sqrt 2, f(\sqrt2) =1$.

(c) $f(x)$ is bounded on the interval $[1, \sqrt 2]$.

*Author O.Kukush*

Comment: By "bounded on the interval $[1, \sqrt 2]$", do you mean the domain is $[1, \sqrt 2]$ or the range is $[1, \sqrt 2]$? If you mean the latter, that is clearly not true because $f(1+\sqrt 2)=f(1)+f(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 2+1 \notin [1, \sqrt 2]$.

Comment: It is certainly the range which is bounded(on $R$) in the given domain @NobleMushtak

Comment: @Jasser So if the range is $[1, \sqrt 2]$, what is the given domain? Is the domain $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @NobleMushtak $1+\sqrt{2}$ is not in the domain for which boundedness is required. "Bounded on the interval $[a,b]$ means there is a $c$ such that for every $x\in[a,b]$, $|f(x)|<c$. You have found an $x$ outside $[1,\sqrt{2}]$, which has no bearing on boundedness.

Comment: The rangle is not $[1,\sqrt{2}]$. @NobleMushtak

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the definition! That makes this much more clear.

Comment: To poster: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Assume $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in[1,\sqrt 2]$.
From $(1)$ we quickly find that $f(ax)=af(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, $a\in\Bbb Q$. 
Pick $n\in\Bbb N$ with $n>M\sqrt 2$ and let $m=\lfloor n\sqrt 2\rfloor$. Then $m<n\sqrt 2<m+1$, hence $\frac m2\sqrt 2<n<\frac m2\sqrt 2+\frac1{\sqrt 2}=\frac m2\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2-1$ and finally
$$1< \underbrace{n+1-\frac m2\sqrt 2}_{=:a}<\sqrt 2.$$
So 
$$\begin{align}M&>|f(a)|\\&=\left|f(n+1)-\frac m2 f(\sqrt 2)\right|\\
&=\left|(n+1)\sqrt 2-\frac m2\right| \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\left|2(n+1)-\frac m2\sqrt 2\right|\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt 2}|(n+1)+a|\\&>\frac{n}{\sqrt 2}\\&>M\end{align}$$
contradiction.

Comment: How do you get that $\frac{m}{2} \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{m}{2} \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}-1$? If I’m not mistaken this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}-1$ and thus $\sqrt{2} = 1$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner I'm pretty sure that's an error. But I think it equals$\frac m2\sqrt 2<n<\frac m2\sqrt 2+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ Multiply by and subtract to get $1 < n - 1 + m\sqrt 2 < \sqrt 2 + 1$ and ... shoot that doesn't work.

Comment: ${1 \over \sqrt 2} = {\sqrt 2 \over 2} = \sqrt 2 - {1 \over 2}\sqrt 2 = \sqrt 2 - 1/\sqrt 2 \ne \sqrt 2  - 1$

Comment: Let $m = 1/2\lfloor 2 \sqrt 2 n \rfloor$ then $m < n\sqrt 2 < m + 1/2 < m + 2 - \sqrt 2$ and then everything else follows.

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)
$$
is the classical [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). It is well know that:

1) if $f$ is real valued ad is continuous at  a point,

or

2) $f$ is not negative for small positive values of x

or

3) $f$ is bounded in an interval ( this is your condition (c))

than this equation has the only solution: $f(x)=f(1)x=kx$.

So, if $f(1)=\sqrt{2}$, we cannot have $f(\sqrt{2})=1$.

If none of such conditions are verified we can have wild solutions of the equations. See [here](https://sunejakobsen.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/cauchy_eng4.pdf).

Comment: Continuoty of $f$ is not required.

Comment: I refers to '' Lectures on Functional equations'' of J Aczél pag. 34.  The continuity at a point is one of the possible conditions. I add the other to my answer.

Comment: I'll research it be what does "not negative for small values of x"?  Does that mean not positive for small *positive* values of x?

Comment: @fleablood: It is ''not negative for small **positive** values of $x$'' (TH. 1 , pag. 34 of the book in previous comment). I'll fix in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the functional equation from (a):
$$
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)
$$

> Solutions to this are called additive functions. Over the rational 
>   numbers, it can be shown using elementary algebra that there is a 
>   single family of solutions, namely $f(x) = cx$ for any arbitrary 
>   rational number $c$
>   Over the real numbers, this is still a family of solutions; however
>   there can exist other solutions that are extremely complicated.

See [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation).

It is not the easy case, making use of (b):
$$
f(x) = c\, x \Rightarrow \\
f(1) = c = \sqrt{2} \\
f(\sqrt{2}) = c \sqrt{2} = 2 \ne 1
$$

Comment: This doesn't address that "extremely complicated" entails "not bounded on any interval"

Comment: Hagen, you are three steps ahead of me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand on Hagen von Eitzen's *excellent* answer and come up with a slightly simpler argument.

$f(x + y) = f(x + y)$ can easily be shown to imply $f(qx) = qf(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q$.

[Because $f(nx) = f(x + ... + x) = f(x) + ... + f(x) = nf(x)$ for natural $n$. And $mf(nx/m) = nf(mx/m) = nf(x)$ therefore $f((n/m)x) = (n/m)f(x)$.]

So let's use this.

Let $n$ be an rational number of arbitrary size.

Let $n\sqrt 2 < n\sqrt 2 + 1 < v < n\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 2$ for some rational $v$. (We can do this because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in the reals, of course.)

Then $1 < v - n\sqrt 2 < \sqrt 2$  and $2n = (\sqrt 2)^2n < \sqrt 2 v$.

But $f(v - n\sqrt 2) = f(v) - f(n\sqrt 2) = v(\sqrt 2) - n >  2n - n = n$.

So $f(x)$ is not bounded on $[1, \sqrt 2]$.

=====

Note the actual interval doesn't matter.  I could have arranged $n\sqrt 2 + a < v < n\sqrt 2 + b$ and the result would have been the same.  Well, I'd have to fudge a bit for negative values of a, but it could be done.

[If $a < 0$ then I'd do $-\sqrt 2 n + a < v < \min(-\sqrt 2 n, -\sqrt 2 n + b) \le \max (-\sqrt 2 n, -\sqrt 2 n + b)$. To get $f(v + \sqrt 2n) < -2n + n = -n$ and $|f(v + \sqrt 2n)| > n$.]